# Scala and JavaScript's JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

When I stringify an object in Scala, the resulting string doesn't match with what JavaScript is expecting the string to be when it attempts to parse the string.

For example, a Scala object may look like the following when the value of Scala's JSON.stringify() is added to the "new Cookie()" instance and the cookie is read by JavaScript.

```
"{\"id\":\"ABCD\"}"
```

However, JavaScript's JSON.parse() method is expecting

```
{"id":"ABCD"}
```

The issue is that I am attempting to save info in a cookie that both Scala and JavaScript can access and modify. I would like to place the info in the cookie using a common format. Is there a way to stringify the JSON in Scala so it can be parsed by JavaScript and visa-versa? Should I use a different format?

================================

UPDATE:

Here is how I am stringifying the JSON and placing the string in a cookie all within Scala:

```
  var sTokenID:String = "ABCD"
  val nDaysExpire:Int = 2000
  val nSecondsExpire:Int = nDaysExpire * 24 * 60 * 60
  val jsonObject = Json.toJson(
    Map(
      "id" -> Json.toJson(sTokenID)
    )
  )
  val sValue:String = Json.stringify(jsonObject)
  val cookie:Cookie = new Cookie(_sCookieID, sValue, Option(nSecondsExpire), "/", scala.None, false, false)
```

Comment: Is this about Scala.js compiled Scala code running in the browser? You clearly indicate so in this case (use the Scala.js tag).

Comment: Also, please post more code how exactly you are calling `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: I updated the original post to include sample code

Comment: I found a workaround. In JavaScript, I search for the occurrence of the double quote character as the 1st character in the cookie's value string. If there is, then I assume the JSON was created in Scala, so I parse the JSON value twice. If there isn't a double quote, then I assume that JSON was created in JavaScript and I only need to parse the JSON value once. It doesn't seem like I have to do anything special to parse the JSON value in Scala.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem I have a json object which is converted to a string, like {"id": "ABCD"}.toString but when I am passing it to logger getting printed as  "{\"id\":\" ABCD\"}" how do I avoid \

Answer (score 0):

jsonObject.toString() should do the trick.

Comment: I had looked into that. When I output that string, it looks just fine - there aren't aren't double quotes preceded by a "/". I think the problem is that somewhere in between setting the value of "new Cookie()" to having the "withCookies()" function write the cookie, the conversion of the string value actually takes place and I am left with a value set in the cookie that is not originally what I intended.